# DataProtection CryptographicException on IIS using a specific key

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, x509certificate, data-protection

I'm writing a ASP.NET Core app to be used on an IIS web farm. To support anti-forgery tokens and other encryption needs, I am attempting to seed my encryption using a certificate shared across the servers in the farm.

My certificate is installed to the Local Computer/Personal store, the certificate path doesn't contain any errors, and the private key was marked as exportable when it was installed, and I granted permissions to the private key to the app pool, iis_iusrs, network service, even "everyone" when all else failed (Yes, I know that's bad, and I'll remove it once it's working!)

Since this is .NET Core and not classic ASP.NET, Instead of using a shared MachineKey I configured Data Protection within the `ConfigureServices()` method in Startup as per [this article by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/compatibility/replacing-machinekey).  But since the `ProtectKeysWithCertificate()` extension method is unavailable for .NET Core applications [as mentioned in this article by MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-encryption-at-rest#x509-certificate), I used `ProtectKeysWithDpapiNG()` instead.  My code looks like this:

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .SetApplicationName("appName")
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"\\computer\share$"))
    .ProtectKeysWithDpapiNG("CERTIFICATE=HashId:<thumbprint>",
        flags: DpapiNGProtectionDescriptorFlags.None);
```

This code runs perfectly fine on my workstation using IISExpress and with a different certificate installed on my computer.  But when running in IIS, I get the following error when I attempt to open a page that's marked to use anti-forgery tokens:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Encryption failed
```

I'm sure I'm missing a step somewhere, but for the life of me, I can't figure out what it is.  Any help out there in internetland would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, I get the same thing when deploying to Service Fabric.